# Transverse field Ising model quantum phase transition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model

I am looking at the quantum phase transition of the transverse field Ising model.

Let:
\begin{equation}
H = -J \sum_{x=1}^{N-1} \sigma_x^3\sigma_{x+1}^3 - B \sum_{x=1}^N \sigma_x^1
\end{equation}

Once I plot the ground state energy as a function of $B/J$ it looks something like this:

[image: Ground state energy]

The first derivative around $B/J = 1$:

[image: first]

And second derivative:

[image: second]

Third derivative:

[image: third]

I am a bit confused. Is this meant to be a first/second/third order phase transition?

The first derivative is smooth, but it is discontinuous at $B/J = 1$. Does this mean that it is a first order phase transition?

If it is not, then the second derivative still converges to the same point at $B/J = 1$, but it is now $\infty$ does it mean it is a second order phase transition?

Otherwise, the third derivative is definitely divergent. Is it then a third order phase transition?

I think that this phase transition should be second order (?), but my first derivative being discontinuous disagrees. Does this mean that my ground state is wrong?

Comment: It is indeed known that the transition at $B/J=1$ is second-order, which means there is singularity (discontinuity) in the second derivative of the energy with respect to the tuning parameter. Your first order derivative does not look discontinuous, so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @MengCheng My first derivative is discontinuous. It has a hole at $x = 1$. But it is smooth. Does that make sense?

Comment: If it is smooth for both $x>1$ and $x<1$ and has the same limit approaching $x=1$ from both sides, then it should just be a continuous curve and the hole should not be there.

Answer (score 1):

**On the divergence near $\mathbf{(\mathit{B/J}) =0}$:** Since $B/J$ has been chosen as the parameter (i.e., $J$ has been chosen as the energy-scale), we have to be careful as we set $B/J$ to zero.

Since $(B/J)\rightarrow0$ could imply $J\rightarrow\infty$, or $B\rightarrow0$, this can anomalously cause the energy to diverge.

**On the order of the phase transition:** The order of a phase transition is (usually) determined by the lowest order of derivative with a singularity. Therefore, by looking at the plots of the derivatives, I would conclude that the transition is second-order.

I hope it helps.